# How many integers in the range [10^20, 10^400] exist such that the sum of their digits is a prime number?

Tags: summation

I have been trying to solve this problem, but I have absolutely no idea how to do it after an hour of focusing on it. Can someone help me with this? I do not know many summation methods and the ones I do know won't work for this problem. The problem is:

How many integers in the range [10^20, 10^400] exist such that the sum of their digits is a prime number?

Comment: Really many integers! Did you try to [program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44089954/trying-to-script-a-program-that-lists-numbers-whose-digits-add-up-to-a-prime-in) it? Where did you get this question?

Comment: That's a huge range. So there's a trick.

Comment: Well, the sum of the digits is between 1 and 3600 (9x400).  So find all those primes.  Find all the single digits that to them.

Comment: This seems like a job for a computer.  Since working with numbers as big as $10^{400}$ is infeasible, the first step I would take is listing out all of the primes from $1$ (*smallest possible digit sum*) to $9\cdot 400$ (*largest possible digit sum*).  For each of these, I would find all unordered partitions with restricted partsize there are (*partsizes between $1$ and $9$*).  From there, multinomial coefficients will tell you how many integers there are with that number of each digit (*being careful about leading zeroes*).  All in all it seems incredibly tedious

Comment: [Another related question from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889703/finding-numbers-whose-digits-sum-to-a-prime).

Comment: According to a poorly-directed edit, this is an open question on a computer science exam or contest, or something.

Comment: @TheCount It might be an online contest but essentially same question has appeared on at least two online judge site (SPOJ and COJ) years before. I've looked at the details of one of them and I've make sure my answer won't help anyone for those task  before I post my answer (this question is missing some critical information which can fundamental speed up the implementation). call me evil ;-p

Comment: @achillehui It's no skin off my back, I just figured I'd make everyone aware. :)

Answer (score 2):

For any formal power series, $p(s) = \sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \alpha_\ell s^\ell$,
in $s$, we will use the notation $[s^\ell] p(s)$ to denote the coefficient $\alpha_\ell$ in front of the monomial $s^\ell$.

For any positive integer $n, p$, let 
$S(n,p)$ be the number of integers in $[ 0, 10^n )$ whose digit sum equals to $p$.

$$S(n,p) = \# \Big\{\; x \in \mathbb{Z} : 0 \le x < 10^n \land \verb/digitsum/(x) = p\;\Big\}$$

When $p > 1$, this is the same as the number of integers in $[0,10^n]$ whose digit sum equals to $p$.
Notice $S(n,p)$ is nothing but the coefficient of $s^p$ in the polynomial.
$$(1 + s + s^2 + \cdots + s^9)^n = \left(\frac{1-s^{10}}{1-s}\right)^n,$$ 
we have
$$\begin{align}
S(n,p) = [s^p]\left(\frac{1-s^{10}}{1-s}\right)^n
&= [s^p]\left(\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\frac{s^{10k}}{(1-s)^n}\right)\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor p/10 \rfloor}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k} [s^{p-10k}]\frac{1}{(1-s)^n}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor p/10 \rfloor} (-1)^k\binom{n}{k} \binom{n+p-10k-1}{n-1}
\end{align}
$$
As a result, the number of integers in $[0,10^n]$ whose digit sum is a prime 
equals to $$\sum_{p \le 9n, \text{ prime}} S(n,p).$$
The number we seek is then given by the formula:
$$\sum_{p \le 3600,\text{ prime}} S(400,p) - \sum_{p \le 180,\text{ prime}} S(20,p)$$

Using the CAS [maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/), we can compute this number using follow commands:

```
nDigitSum(n,p)    := sum((-1)^k*binomial(n,k)*binomial(n+p-10*k-1,n-1),k,0,floor(p/10));
nDigitSumP(n,p)   := if(primep(p)) then nDigitSum(n,p) else 0;
nPrimeDigitSum(n) := sum(nDigitSumP(n,p),p,2,9*n);
result: nPrimeDigitSum(400)-nPrimeDigitSum(20);
set_display('ascii);
print(result)$
```

The end result is a huge number.

```
120888176383650031282552770253397424966
787427338099956413212993113280784696724
260497913697175095791242072593820131206
950041671051172505624445972616015650856
897817470371767968533342280236305697259
770415946860510971481033938597951687102
427797729701959351072202940307227505127
619575131698465059016193882263000348068
314626029805761909881907547855416276442
770197900432763462801585585614397666309
3829340446
```

From this number, we find the digit sums of about $12.1\%$ of numbers in $[10^{20},10^{400}]$ is prime. This ratio is compatible with the number $\frac{1}{\log(3600)} \approx 12.21\%$ and hence consistent 
with the fact the density of prime number falls of like $\frac{1}{\log N}$.

Comment: This question is directly from an ongoing competition hsctf.com. We would be grateful if you could censor this question until 6/28. Thank you.

Comment: @AlanYan you can flag for the moderator to lock this question. Since I have seen essentially same question on two online judge sites (the question isn't ongoing on those sites anymore). I'm not going to censor this answer.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for responding quickly.